# FontAwesome not showing without www

Tags: css, web, drupal, drupal-7, font-awesome

I have my site which works with fontawesome but when I type my site without www. before, it doesn't show the icons.
When I put www. in front they show op.
What do I need to change. the site in question is [www.bluestar.be](http://www.bluestar.be) and [bluestar.be](http://bluestar.be)

edit: this is my console:

```
Access to Font at 'http://www.bluestar.be/sites/all/themes/rhythm/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0' from origin 'http://bluestar.be' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://bluestar.be' is therefore not allowed access.
```

SOLUTION
I added these lines to the code to redirect the site.com to the www.site.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Both Links are working fine....

Comment: You have to modify your .htaccess file and set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". to allow font-awesome for both cases. see this [http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164096/font-awesome-not-working-when-using-http]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to you .htaccess in root of your drupal project.

Add these lines

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE"

and you're good to go.
Make sure you have modrewrite enabled on your server.

Comment: when I add this I get an Internal Server Error